# Windows 10 64 bit - Stuck in 16 bit colour depth

Tags: windows-10, color-depth

Recently I tried to install a game on my PC which is not compatible with Windows 10. Upon running the game my monitor started to flash ridiculously fast and left a burn on the screen for a while.

After closing the game down I noticed that my screen had changed to have 16 bit colour depth however when I check my graphics card settings I am running in 32 bit colour depth.

I have already reinstalled Windows and reinstalled my graphics card drivers. Could this be a problem with the monitor?

Comment: What type of monitor? Have you tried adjusting the settings on the monitor itself?

Comment: I am **_so_** curious as to what game you were running that "caused" this.

Comment: The game was Guitar Hero 3

Comment: Any follow-up to this? Curious whether or not you've solved this issue / gained additional information.

Comment: You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Troubleshoot**

The monitor is probably going defective as a result of age. Take the following steps in order to be sure nothing else is to blame:

1. Reset the Monitor (using the buttons on the monitor itself, NOT the operating system).
2. Connect different cables, both power and video (DVI/HDMI).
3. Try a different monitor (if you don't own an additional monitor either borrow one from someone else, or bring your computer to them).

If none of these steps solve the problem it is very likely that the monitor is at fault. Use the warranty if still applicable.

**Details**

It could be the power supply but more likely the capacitors. Another symptom I've encountered is the monitor flashing slowly when just turned on (cold state) and it gradually increasing in frequency (strobe effect), then after a while it stops and is usable again.

Also, modern day monitors report all supported modes to the connected device (via digital output / input). The fact that you can still select 32-bit within the control panel convinces me even more that it is defective.

It is very unlikely this happened because of installing an older game on Windows 10. Switching modes upon launch might have been the tipping point, but age is probably the real issue.

Comment: I've only had this monitor around 9 months, should I send it back under warranty and see if this makes a difference?

Comment: I would personally make sure it is actually the monitor that's defective and not the GPU. Mentioned above: (1) Reset the Monitor (2) Switch cables, power and DVI/HDMI (3) Try a different monitor... Definitely send it in for repair after that, given that there's still warranty on it.